# Is it possible to run two Lightning Network nodes on top of single Bitcoin Core node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network

I would like to simultaneously run LND and Eclair nodes on top of single Bitcoin Core bitcoind node. Is it possible? I wasn't been able to pull it off so far.

If possible, how to set up ZMQ and listen-tcp?

---

Thanks Rene, I have managed to do it. Works flawlessly. :)

Listen addresses must be different, eg. 0.0.0.0:9735 and 0.0.0.0:9736, and both  need to be open in router. Also rpclisten must be different, eg: 127.0.0.1:10009 and 127.0.0.1:10019

When opening channel between them use localhost address, eg. 03di28did92d2dh92d29d229d299239r98398r@127.0.0.1:9736

Answer (score 1):

Technically it should be possible. You can find a pretty straight forward description in the lnd docs at: https://dev.lightning.community/tutorial/01-lncli/index.html

I am running several c-lightning nodes on top of the one Bitcoin node that I'm running. In clightning you just have to specify a different data directory and port for each node. Also on this machine I have an lnd node running.

I could give you examples how to do this with c Lightning but you asked for lnd / eclair. As said I don't see any reason why it would not work with the other implementations but I have not checked it yet. This referring you to their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With c-lightning there are no restrictions to use as many as you want LN nodes with single bitcoind (i am hosting LN nodes as a service, and by default these use one single bitcoind, just with different RPC credentials).

I would like to point to these instructions: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#using-bitcoind-or-litecoind

> Don't connect more than two or three instances of lnd to bitcoind. With the default bitcoind settings, having more than one instance of lnd, or lnd plus any application that consumes the RPC could cause lnd to miss crucial updates from the backend.

I think this is related to ZMQ. But i am not sure.

I am not aware how it is with Eclair.